# How can my android app google maps draw tracks of my movements with gps on google map sdk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation, google-polyline

I want a tracking line behind my location pointer which is moving to draw a it, so that we can see the route the person takes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maJlu.jpg)
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

private LocationListener locationListener;
private LocationManager locationManager;

private final long MIN_TIME = 1000;  // 1 second
private final long MIN_DIST = 5; //1 meters

private LatLng latLng;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    com.example.employeetrackingstarter.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {

            latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            googleMap.clear();
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).flat(true).title("My Position").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker5)));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        }
    };

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DIST, locationListener);

    }
    catch (SecurityException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use polyline, and when your user change location, draw it. You can see video [link](https://youtu.be/VR8RKM9LTyA). First position its place where you start and second place its you current location.